# magento stuck on state payment_review

Tags: payment-methods, order-state

i having problem with order state. When customer order a product, no matter what payment option is select, order stuck on state "payment_review" instead to be state "new".

If I manually change state in "new", and after creating inovice state change in "payment_review" again.

I think it's a problem in database, because I was delete all magento files and insert new (fresh) magento with same database and problem was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to change `an order state`  to `payment_review` then must need check order is `capable to change the state to payment review` .

In this case you can check using payment model  of order object.

```
$Order->getPayment()->canReviewPayment().
```

If this value is true then you can change the status to `payment_review`

Comment: I think you don't understand me.
Every order I made get state "payment_review". I want to change this state to "new". No matter on payment methods